# Checking if there is no error in db CI 3

Tags: codeigniter-3

Checking if there is no error in db transaction.
I currently upgraded my CI 2.1.4 application to CI 3.0.x application, everything seems fine except the code below.

**Models**

```
 $result = array();
 $result['error'] = $this->db->_error_number(); // Changed to $this->db->error();
 $result['message'] = $this->db->_error_message(); // How do I replace it with CI new function for error message?
 return $result;
```

**Controllers**

How do I check if there is no problem in controller?

```
if(!$result['error']['code'])
{       

// success          

} else 
    {   

// Error    

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of version 3.0.x, db error check was modified.

In your models, you can use:

```
// run the wanted operation
if($this->db->...)
{
    // it ran okay
}
else
{
    // returns array('code' => '...', 'message' => '...')
    $error = $this->db->error(); 

    switch($error['code']){ 
       case <ERROR-NUMBER>:
           throw new Exception("<CUSTOM-MESSAGE>");
           break;
       default:
           throw new Exception($error['message']);
    }
}
```

Then, you can catch exceptions on your controllers:

```
try
{
    // call model function
    $this->{MODEL-NAME}->{FUNCTION-NAME}(...);
}
catch (Exception $ex)
{
    // treats the Exception 
    // $ex->getMessage();
}
```

If you want to get errors from the database, do not forget to set `db_debug = FALSE` in the `config/database.php` file.